# Missing htons while building dnssd gem for Ruby 1.9.1

Tags: c, ruby, rubygems

I've been trying to get the latest version of the DNSSD plugin to work with Ruby 1.9.1 but ran into a few problems. I've outlined the steps I have taken so far, maybe someone here will be able to figure out what else is going wrong.

1. Tried installing the current version, using: `sudo gem19 install dnssd` Gem install failed citing htons could not be found.

checking for htons()... no
need function htons

2. Checked the man pages for htons() (from what I understand htons converts a string to network byte order [big-endian] if needed)
3. Added the relevant include for htons() #include  according to Mac OSX 10.5 man pages.
4. Ran ruby19 extconf.rb and htons() not found, ruby (1.8) succeeds.

DNSSD v0.7.0 github mirror http://github.com/jqr/dnssd/tree/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htons does not convert a string, it converts a short (16 bit) from host-byte-order to network-byte-order.

It may (probably is) implemented as a macro. On my system (Debian Etch), it lives in the file /usr/include/netinet/in.h. This is owned by the package libc6-dev, which is the development part of the standard C library.

Not sure how this is organized on OSX, but you should verify that you have C development libraries installed.

Comment: thanks bstpierre, I'm sure this is Ruby 1.9.1 specific as with Ruby 1.8 htons is found on my system, rather than whether the libraries are present.